# ¿Cómo ordeno un arreglo de objetos dependiendo la suma de sus atributos?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Estoy desarrollando un aplicación de ventas. Tengo 2 arreglos de objetos, uno con los nombres de los vendedores y otro con las ventas realizadas del mes. Mi idea era ordenar el arreglo de nombres dependiendo del que hizo más ventas al que hizo menos usando la información del arreglo de ventas.
Intenté realizar un `reduce` sumando las ventas de cada vendedor, pero no se me ocurre cómo realizarlo para los 3 vendedores y luego de eso compararlos para ordenar el arreglo de objetos de nombres.

```js
const vendedores = [{id:1,name: 'juan', age: 23},{id:2,name: 'adrian', age: 32},{id:3,name: 'apolo', age: 45}];

const ventas= [{equipo: 'frances', vendedorId: 2, cantidad: 234},{equipo: 'italiano', vendedorId: 3, cantidad: 24},{equipo: 'polaco', vendedorId: 1, cantidad: 534},{equipo: 'frances', vendedorId: 2, cantidad: 1234},{equipo: 'frances', vendedorId: 3, cantidad: 2342}];

const mejoresVendedores= () => {
//no se como hacerlo para los 3 vendedores y despues compararlos para ordenar el arreglo de nombres
 ventas.reduce((sum, value) => ( value.vendedorId == 1 ? sum + value.area : sum), 0);

}
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento? Dices qu tu idea es ordenar en base al array secundario, pero ¿cómo se ve tu idea en código? Recuerda que una de las recomendaciones que se hacen en [ask] es el incluir un fragmento de código a modo de [mcve]. Te recomiendo [edit] tu pregunta para agregar código (vamos, que no es necesario que funcione) y enfocar tu pregunta a ese código, ya sea por errores que te dé, o por cómo funciona X o Y. También te invito a realizar el [tour] y ganar tu primera medalla.

Comment: Posible [duplicado](/q/530293).

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez no es la mejor forma, pero creo que podrías resolver con esto:

```
const ordenar = vendedores.map((vendedor) => {
    vendedor.ventas = ventas.reduce((suma, vta) => { 
                            suma += (vta.vendedorId === vendedor.id)?1:0; 
                            return suma; 
                        }, 0);
    return vendedor;
});

ordenar.sort((a, b) => b.ventas > a.ventas);
```

Hice un par de pruebas y al parecer funciona, me devuelve esto:

```
[ { id: 2, name: 'adrian', age: 32, ventas: 2 },
  { id: 3, name: 'apolo', age: 45, ventas: 2 },
  { id: 1, name: 'juan', age: 23, ventas: 1 } ]
```

Espero te ayude o te de un norte de lo que ocupas hacer.

Mi recomendación seria meter en el primer objeto la cantidad de ventas que cada vendedor ha hecho como arreglo, así puedes tener el numero de ventas por cada uno y ordenas basado en eso.

Saludos

Comment: Se me estaba ocurriendo algo asi... pero yo creo que no deberías sumar "1" sino sumar la cantidad de ventas (o sea `vta.cantidad`)

Comment: Cierto, si la idea es ordenar en base al monto de dinero, seria con `cantidad`, yo base en el numero ventas no el monto. Pero tienes razón. @Pipe

Answer (score 0):

Primero necesitas ordenar el arreglo **ventas** usando el campo **cantidad** de mayor a menor. Una vez ordenado el arreglo, necesitarías juntar los 2 arreglos por medio de su ID. Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
const vendedores = [
  {id:1,name: 'juan', age: 23},
  {id:2,name: 'adrian', age: 32},
  {id:3,name: 'apolo', age: 45}
];

const ventas = [
  {equipo: 'frances', vendedorId: 2, cantidad: 234},
  {equipo: 'italiano', vendedorId: 3, cantidad: 24},
  {equipo: 'polaco', vendedorId: 1, cantidad: 534},
  {equipo: 'frances', vendedorId: 2, cantidad: 1234},
  {equipo: 'frances', vendedorId: 3, cantidad: 2342}
];

function multiSort(array, sortObject = {}) {
    const sortKeys = Object.keys(sortObject);

    // Devuelve una matriz si no se proporciona ningún objeto de ordenación.
    if (!sortKeys.length) {
        return array;
    }

    // Cambie los valores de las claves sortObject a -1, 0 o 1.
    for (let key in sortObject) {
        sortObject[key] = sortObject[key] === 'desc' || sortObject[key] === -1 ? -1 : (sortObject[key] === 'skip' || sortObject[key] === 0 ? 0 : 1);
    }

    const keySort = (a, b, direction) => {
        direction = direction !== null ? direction : 1;

        if (a === b) { // Si los valores son los mismos, no cambie de posición.
            return 0;
        }

        // Si b > a, multiplique por -1 para obtener la dirección inversa.
        return a > b ? direction : -1 * direction;
    };

    return array.sort((a, b) => {
        let sorted = 0;
        let index = 0;

        // Ciclo while hasta que se clasifique (-1 o 1) o hasta que se hayan procesado las claves de clasificación.
        while (sorted === 0 && index < sortKeys.length) {
            const key = sortKeys[index];

            if (key) {
                const direction = sortObject[key];

                sorted = keySort(a[key], b[key], direction);
                index++;
            }
        }

        return sorted;
    });
}

// Juntamos los 2 arreglos por medio de su ID
const mergeArrays = (arr1 = [], arr2 = []) => {
   let res = [];
   res = arr1.map(obj => {
      const index = arr2.findIndex(el => el["id"] == obj["vendedorId"]);
      const { name } = index !== -1 ? arr2[index] : {};
      return {
         ...obj,
         name
      };
   });
   return res;
};

// En esta línea puedes cambiar el orden ya sea 'asc' o 'desc'
console.log(mergeArrays(multiSort(ventas, {cantidad: 'desc'}), vendedores));
```